# A function in django view returns a list of dictionary. How can I get value to particular key in its robot test case

Tags: python, django, robotframework

Django view function returns:
[{u'Name': u'Test Name', u'Description': u'Test', u'Marks': u'10'}]

I am Calling the API using RequestsLibrary in Robot and my response seems like a dictionary response but I am unable to fetch value for any particular key.

Comment: what have you tried till now ? there are lots of built in keywords to do these tasks easily in collections library.

Comment: Please add what you have tried so far; accessing dictionaries or deeply nested json is not hard in RF, we'll help you clear out any errors.

Comment: I have tried to get the the API response and traverse it over by using the functions like Get From Dictionary, Create DIctionary.
But the issue is Its not reading the API response as a dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

You are having a response with a list of dictionary. You can either use index or a loop to access the dictionary

```
A = [{u'Name': u'Test Name', u'Description': u'Test', u'Marks': u'10'}]
print A[0]['Name'] == 'Test Name'
```

Comment: Hi Rakesh,
It works in python, but I am having trouble using it in Robotframework.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured a work around.

created a function in my core which converts the API response to a dictionary and called that function.

```
def createRobotDict(self,obj):
    return ast.literal_eval(obj)
```